# Phaser.js Implementing Minecraft lighting

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So, I was looking into making minecraft/terraria block lighting

[image]

(like how some tiles are dark)

So far, I've seen the high level idea being
"set the sky block to the max light level, and reduce by x for every block, get light level by averaging light levels"

So my question is Mainly, How can I implement this in phaser? would I need to give every tile the value and calculate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tilemap/get-chebyshev-distance), that covers answers you question *(if I undertand your question correct)*.

**Here a slightly alter version of the example:**
*(it is a very crude example, to show case the idea)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload (){
    this.load.image('tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/catastrophi_tiles_16.png');
    this.load.tilemapCSV('map', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/csv/catastrophi_level2.csv');
}

function create () {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click to change light position')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setDepth(100)
        .setStyle({fontFamily: 'Arial'});
            
    let map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map', tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    let tileset = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0);

    let lightSource = {x: 0, y: 0};
    
    updateMap(map, lightSource);
    
    this.input.on('pointerdown', (pointer) => updateMap(map, pointer));
    
}

function updateMap (map, lightSource) {
    let fullLightDistanceInTiles = 3; 
    let origin = map.getTileAtWorldXY(lightSource.x, lightSource.y);

    map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
            origin.x,
            origin.y,
            tile.x,
            tile.y
        ) - fullLightDistanceInTiles;

        tile.setAlpha(1 - 0.1 * dist);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

It basically just calculates the distance from the player to the tiles and set the alpha value. You would have to modify it so, that the distance is caluclate from a fixed sun/light position or so. *(and recalculation would only be necessary if the sun/light position move)*

> if you don't want to set the alpha on the map tiles you could create a second layer with only black/grey tiles above, and set the alpha on this layer, but this would *muddy* the colors abit.

**Alternatively, if:** the light is horizontal and has the same level, you could simply overlay a gradient image or so. This would be better for performance and less work.

**Here a demo using a phaser generated gradient:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload (){
    this.load.image('tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/catastrophi_tiles_16.png');
    this.load.tilemapCSV('map', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/csv/catastrophi_level2.csv');      
}

function create () {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'fixed horizontal darkness')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setDepth(100)
        .setStyle({fontFamily: 'Arial'});
            
    let map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map', tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    let tileset = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0);
    
    var graphicsOverlay = this.add.graphics();

    graphicsOverlay.fillGradientStyle(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0,0,1,1);
    graphicsOverlay.fillRect(0, config.height/3, config.width,  config.height*2/3);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```